# Sax parsing in GoLang - Slow speed

Tags: .net, go

Given the following code in C# / .NET Core 2.1

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var totalAmountSeconds = 0;

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\temp\XML.xml"))
        {
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            var elementCounter = 0;

            stopWatch.Start();

            foreach (var element in XmlReaderUtils.EnumerateAxis(reader, new[] { "Node" }))
            {
                elementCounter += 1;
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();
            totalAmountSeconds += stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds;

            Console.WriteLine("Total '<Node />' elements: " + elementCounter);
        }

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"XML.xml"))
        {
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            var elementCounter = 0;

            stopWatch.Start();

            foreach (var element in XmlReaderUtils.EnumerateAxis(reader, new[] { "ArticleGroup" }))
            {
                elementCounter += 1;
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();
            totalAmountSeconds += stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds;

            Console.WriteLine("Total '<ArticleGroup />' elements: " + elementCounter);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total amount of required seconds: " + totalAmountSeconds);
    }
}

public static class XmlReaderUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> EnumerateAxis(XmlReader reader,
        string[] elements)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (!elements.Contains(reader.Name)) continue;

                    yield return XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do believe that an exact copy of this code in GoLang should be the following:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    xmlFile, _ := os.Open("XML.xml")
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)

    amountOfElements := 0
    for {
        t, _ := decoder.Token()
        if t == nil {
            break
        }

        // Inspect the type of the token just read.
        switch se := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            if se.Name.Local == "Node" {
                amountOfElements++
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("Total '<Node />' elements: %v\n", amountOfElements)

    xmlFile, _ = os.Open("XML.xml")
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    decoder = xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)

    amountOfElements = 0
    for {
        t, _ := decoder.Token()
        if t == nil {
            break
        }

        // Inspect the type of the token just read.
        switch se := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            if se.Name.Local == "ArticleGroup" {
                amountOfElements++
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("Total '<ArticleGroup />' elements: %v\n", amountOfElements)

    fmt.Printf("Total elapsed time: %v", time.Since(start))
}
```

The code execution in .NET takes 1 minutes, while in GoLang, it takes 2 minutes.
The .NET version is built using Release configuration, go GoLang a `go build` is executed.

I expected GoLang to be faster but indeed it turned out to be slower?
Is this normal or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`xml.NewDecoder` contains two methods to read XML token from file - [Token()](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.Token) and [RawToken()](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.RawToken).

`Tocken()` contains some additional checks for StartElement and EndElement match and translate name space prefixes to their corresponding URLs.

Try `RawToken()` if you do note these features.

P.S. In C# you read 2 different files, in GO you read the same file twice. Can it be that second file is smaller/simpler in C# sample?

Comment: That's not the case. I just changed the filenames is the copy paste to SO, in both examples I read the same file twice. And I need the 'Start' and 'End' elements, so I do require `Token`.

Comment: @Complexity I do not see usage of `EndElement` in your code. `StartElement` is returned with `RawToken`. Did you check if `RawTaken` improve performance?

Comment: I'm quite now so with RawToken() it doesn't work quitely. You mind providing an example?

Answer (score 0):

**The question "what language is faster?" is a common one, but fraught with complications, consider:**

- the quality of compilers for a language may differ between platforms
- there may be multiple ways of compiling a language with differing
  performance tradeoffs on any given platform
- a language may be slow when used "idiomatically" but capable of
  producing fast code if you really want to. Would it make sense, for
  instance, to compare a C# program that uses lots of unsafe and simd
  intrinsics to a pure Go implementation, for instance? It might, just
  depends what you want to measure. But you can be sure it will anger
  one side or the other no matter what choice you make.
- there are millions of different kind of programs and millions of ways
  to write each one of them. these will all have different performance
  needs and trade offs.
- one language may be faster than another, but high quality libraries
  in the ecosystem of the slower language may allow you to easily
  create faster programs. Think of, for instance, Python with it's
  machine learning and math ecosystems, backed with super fast C code.
  Is it fair to compare python calling into C libs vs C#? Sure, depends
  what you want to know. But people will argue!

**All of that said, you can expect some general trends in Go vs C# performance:**

- Go will tend to have shorter GC pauses, which is great for things
  like games
- But Go will tend to spend more total time doing GC than C#, which is
  bad for not games.
- Go has more expensive FFI (bad for games!)
- Because Go is normally ahead of time compiled, and C# is normally
  Jitted,Go programs will generally start up quicker. Good for command
  line programs! But, you *can* ahead of time compile C# too.
- Idiomatic C#, with lots of linq calling into virtual functions and
  everything behind interfaces, may tend to be slower than idiomatic
  Go, which tends to be lower level.
- C# will tend to have a higher performance ceiling when you want it,
  and the benchmark game bears this out. C# tends to beat Go, but the
  solutions have lots of unsafe and other tricks.